# Is there a way to get game listing info from Steam into a desktop app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, steam, steam-web-api

I am writing a desktop app which would greatly benefit from some way to get Steam store listing data. I would like to find a game's developer, name autocomplete info, some description, pricing or images… whatever's possible.

Is there any way to do this, through Steam or a third-party API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of your own games only.
Quoting the official Steam Web API documentation,

> **GetOwnedGames (v0001)**
>
> GetOwnedGames returns a list of games a player owns along with some
>   playtime information, if the profile is publicly visible. Private,
>   friends-only, and other privacy settings are not supported unless you
>   are asking for your own personal details (ie the WebAPI key you are
>   using is linked to the steamid you are requesting).
>
> Example URL:
>   http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960434622&format=json

More info:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Comment: Note that this only returns the app ID and playtime.